# Multi-Join Query timeout issue

Tags: sql-server

I wasn't able to find this in searching other questions. I am trying to do a series of joins, nothing terribly complex. The problem is that I continue to get the error:

***"Msg 15884, Level 16, State 1, Line 110
Distributed query timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the distributed operation."***

I am using SSMS on top of Azure. Ultimately, I am trying to get all records in the database for 6 people. Which should only return approx 2500 records based on other queries I've done. The issue is (I think) that the Views that I am joining are at the small end thousands and at the large end billions of records. I do not have access to the tables themselves, just views and cannot write to the database. So unfortunately I cannot just make one small table and then another step to merge everything in.

The code so far is below. THis is probably the 10th iteration I've tried. Eventually I just gave up on the conditions and just inputted the PatientIDs that I wanted.

What am I doing (or not) that is making this not finish?

```
SELECT  
  Dx.ClaimId
    ,Dx.PatientId
    ,Patient.PatientGender
    ,patient.PatientBirthYear
    ,Patient.PatientZip3
    ,Dx.Npi
    ,HCP.[HCP Last Name]
    ,HCP.[HCP Specialty]
    ,HCP.[HCP Practice Location]
    ,HCP.[HCP State]
    ,HCP.POSTCODE_CD
    ,Dx.DiagnosisCode
    ,Dx.DiagnosisTypeCode
    ,Px.ProcedureCode
    ,Px.ReferringNpi
    ,HCP2.[HCP Last Name]
    ,HCP2.[HCP Specialty]
    ,HCP2.[HCP Practice Location]
    ,HCP2.[HCP State]
    ,HCP2.POSTCODE_CD

FROM  [Nimbus].[mxs].dx DX
LEFT JOIN [Nimbus].[mxs].Px PX ON Dx.ClaimId = PX.ClaimId and (DX.PatientId =106753907
OR DX.PatientId = 240884005
OR DX.PatientId = 811094164
OR DX.PatientId = 473903167
OR DX.PatientId = 1396954203
OR DX.PatientId = 879348405)
LEFT JOIN [Nimbus].[mdm].HCPInfo HCP on HCP.[HCP NPI] = Dx.Npi
LEFT JOIN [Nimbus].[mdm].HCPInfo HCP2 on HCP.[HCP NPI] = Px.ReferringNpi
LEFT JOIN [Nimbus].[mxs].Patient Patient on Patient.PatientId = Dx.PatientId and (DX.PatientId =106753907
OR DX.PatientId = 240884005
OR DX.PatientId = 811094164
OR DX.PatientId = 473903167
OR DX.PatientId = 1396954203
OR DX.PatientId = 879348405)
```

Comment: Why not use an `IN` here, rather than all those `OR` clauses? As for the error, it's telling you that the query took took too long. Do you have any indexes to help the RDBMS here?

Comment: THank you. I got the same error when using IN, but tried that as well. Changed to OR just to see whether it made a difference.

Is there a way to check? I only have access to the views which I did not create. Accessing another company's server- so I can simply ask unless there is an easier way.

Comment: I would suggest talking to the company that supports the database then; performance tuning is their responsibility